# How to implement live updates on page using AJAX?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, google-app-engine

I'm using Google App Engine, Python and JQuery.  My application is similar to Twitter in that it allows users to publish messages/status updates.  I want the home page to display live updates (just like Twitter's homepage) so that if a new message is posted, it appears top on the list of my home page.

I'm looking for a design pattern to get started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen the new [channel api](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview.html) on GAE? it will basically abstract away the polling - allowing you to push bi-directionally. Oh, and i've linked to the code sample (in Python + JS).

Hope this helps

Comment: Awesome - it's baked right into GAE!  Checking it out now . . .

Answer (score 1):

On Google App Engine, you probably want to use [the new Channel API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview.html).  It allows you to declare a channel on the server, using code which looks like:

```
token = channel.create_channel('my_key')
```

... and then on the client you can use something like ...

```
  <script>
    channel = new goog.appengine.Channel('{{ token }}');
    socket = channel.open();
    socket.onmessage = onMessage;
  </script>
```

There's plenty of examples on Google's site.

Answer (score 0):

There are various techniques out there, they are usually referred to as "Comet" or "Reverse Ajax". I don't know about your specific technologies, but that ought to get you on the right track.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29

Comment: Typical comet techniques will not work on App Engine.  On GAE one must use the channel API as Chris and flying crab point out.